# Переход с .Net Framework на .Net Core

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core

Всем доброй ночи. У меня имеется WPF-проект на .Net Framework 4.7, возможно ли его перенести на .Net Core 6.0 или другие более новые? Если возможно, то как? Я бы оочень был благодарен за информацию

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/core/porting/upgrade-assistant-wpf-framework

Comment: @EvgeniyZ - оперативненько! :-)

Comment: Можно и нужно. :)

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался. В командной строке потребовалось всего 2 команды:
upgrade-assistant analyze
upgrade-assistant upgrade
Отдельная благодарность EvgeniyZ